# Python error: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, email, smtplib

What I am doing is taking information from a web page and attempting to put it into an e-mail in a format like:
First Name: first \n#first is a variable
Last Name: last #last is a variable

Below is my code:

```
import smtplib
import base64

from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEMultipart('relative')
msg['Subject'] = 'Confirmation E-Mail'
msg['From'] = "none"
msg['To'] = email
text1 = "First Name: ", first_name, "<br>Last Name: ", last_name
part1 = MIMEText(text1, 'html')

s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.sendmail(email, email, msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

first_name and last_name are pulled from the web page!

Comment: Although the question has already been answered I'll just add: The lines that you wrote were "the rest of the errors" are not other errors.  There was a single error here resulting in a traceback.  You can Google 'python tracebacks' to learn more.  When you get a traceback it's best to post the entire thing starting with the word "Traceback" all the way to the last line containing the exception message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MIMEText takes a string as its first argument. You're creating text1 as a tuple. You need something more like

```
"First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s" % (first_name, last_name)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the OP's original code was `text1 = "First Name: ", first_name, "\nLast Name: ", last_name`.  This is an understandable conflation with the functionality of the `print` statement that allows it to take multiple arguments and join them together with spaces.  This is not, however, how one normally concatenates strings in Python.

Comment: Thank you, I can figure out the rest from here :). Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you need to attach part1 to msg:

```
msg.attach(part1)
```

you can also find a good example of how to send a multipart email message in the [Python Documenation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html)